# Convert UTF8 string to UTF-16 in .net

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, utf-8

I have a string from  UTF8 and want to convert that to Unicode (UTF16). Please help.

Comment: I suggest you read this article first by Joel Splosky http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Hi @Fraisal, isn't UTF8 an implementation of Unicode? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Comment: UTF8 *is* Unicode. Do you mean that you want to convert it to UTF-16, which is teh Unicode encoding used by .NET?

Comment: All strings in C# are in Unicode. Be more specific in string source and target.

Comment: @jalf, yes i want to convert it to utf16

Comment: @Faisal So you've got a file rather than a string. Is that correct?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have a file and you know that encoding of the file is UTF8 you can use `StreamReader` to read the file as if it is encoded in UTF8.
Regarding conversion from UTF8 to Unicode, you are comparing 2 different things. Check the link in my comment to your question.
`System.Text.UTF8Encoding` is UTF8 `System.Text.UnicodeEncoding` is UTF16. Check [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0440__I18N-Internationalization/ConvertUTF8fromUnicode.htm) for conversion. You would be using `Encoding.Convert()`

Comment: `System.Text.UnicodeEncoding` is the thing I was looking for the past few hours.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/744y86tc%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Pass in your UTF-8 encoded text, as a byte array. The function returns a standard .net string which is encoded in UTF-16.